Role of Normal Force in Non-Uniform Vertical Circular Motion
Question
There are 2 instances of vertical non-circular motion that I don't quite understand.
Case 1

Description
In this situation, a marble of mass $m$ is moving on the inside of a vertical circular track, meaning that it is affected by gravity.
Everything else stays ideal:

The size of the marble is negligible
No friction or air resistance
No torque applied to the marble; translational motion only

I've marked 3 possible positions to this marble: bottom (A), top-right (B), and top (C). They all experience the same weight $\vec{F_g}$. Each of them experiences a normal force $\vec{F_N}$, travel at a tangential velocity of $\vec{v}$, and are at an angle $\theta$ measured anticlockwise relative to the downward direction. The track has radius $R$.
Concern

From what I know, the marble still experiences a normal force, despite the fact it's not accelerating upwards in any way; this is due to its velocity $\vec{v}$ trying to push it into the track. Does that mean the marble still experiences a normal force pointing downwards at C?

From what I know, the following is true for the marble:

In the radial direction, $F_g \cos(\pi-\theta) + F_N = m \frac{v^2}{R}$
In the tangential direction, $F_g \sin(\pi-\theta) = m \alpha R$, where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration of the marble.


The equation in the radial direction seems to suggest that there is always a force $F_N$ that can support the marble's circular motion, with a magnitude of $m \frac{v^2}{R} - F_g \cos(\pi-\theta)$, no matter its velocity. However, that isn't true, as the marble will fall mid-track if it starts the circular motion at some velocity $v < v_0$. What am I missing?
Also, any tangential acceleration acted upon the marble will affect its radial acceleration too, as its tangential velocity has changed. That means when the marble travels at some initial velocity $v_0$, it is possible to predict its velocity $v(t)$ at any time $t$. Hence, it should be possible to find out the marble's centripetal acceleration, and therefore its experienced normal force, at any point in time. Is this true? If so, how would this be done? I've tried deriving a relationship using the force equations above, as well as the rotational kinematic equations $\omega = {\omega}_0 + \alpha t$ and $v = \omega R$, but to no avail.



Case 2

Description
In this situation, a marble of mass $m$ is moving on the outside of a vertical circular track.
Everything else about the situation is identical to that of case 1.
I've marked 4 possible positions to this marble: top (A), up-and-slightly-right (B), right-and-slightly-up (C), and right (D). They all experience the same weight $\vec{F_g}$. Each of them experiences a normal force $\vec{F_N}$, travel at a tangential velocity of $\vec{v}$, and are at an angle $\theta$ measured clockwise relative to the upward direction. The track has radius $R$.
Concern

In these situations, the force equations are as follows:

In the radial direction, $F_g \cos(\theta) - F_N = m \frac{v^2}{R}$
In the tangential direction, $F_g \sin(\theta) = m \alpha R$, where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration of the marble.


Again, just by looking at the equations, it seems like there's always some force $F_N = m \frac{v^2}{R} + F_g \cos(\theta)$ that will keep the marble on the track no matter what. Again, this is not true. In many cases, when the marble reaches some angle ${\theta}_c$, it will reach a velocity of $v_c$ such that it flies off the track and no longer experiences any normal force. What did I do wrong?
I also have trouble deriving a relationship among tangential acceleration, radial acceleration, tangential velocity, and experienced normal force, just like in case 1. Is the derivation possible, and if so, how would this be approached?




regarding case one (point 2 bullet 3), if the velocity is low enough, then the normal force will become negative, which does not make sense (you would need the force to attract the mass towards the rail, rather than pushing it out).


... the marble still experiences a normal force... this is due to its velocity $v$ trying to push it into the track ...

A better way to think of it is that if the marble is moving in a circle with radius $R$ and speed $v$ then it must experience a centripetal force $\frac {mv^2} R$. In both scenarios you describe, this centripetal force is the net sum of the normal force and the radial component of the marble's weight.
There is, however, a constraint, which is that the normal force must act inwards in Case 1 and outwards in Case 2. So if we get to a point in the marble's motion where the normal force would have to act in a non-physical direction (i.e. outwards in Case 1; inwards in Case 2) in order to achieve the required centripetal force then we can conclude that the marble cannot be following a circular path at this point.
In Case 1 we have
$\displaystyle F_N = \frac {mv^2} R - mg \cos(\pi - \theta)$
where a positive value of $F_N$ indicates that it is acting inwards. In this case the constraint tells us that for the marble to follow the inside surface of the circular track, then we must have
$F_N \ge 0
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {mv^2} R \ge mg \cos(\pi - \theta)$
While the ball is in the lower half of the track ($|\theta| \le \frac \pi 2$) this is fine, since $\cos (\pi - \theta)$ is negative. However, in the upper half of the track, $\cos (\pi - \theta)$ increases and $v$ decreases as the marble goes higher, so there may come a point where
$\frac {mv^2} R = mg \cos(\pi - \theta)$
and after this point the marble will leave the track and will move ballistically.
You can apply the same reasoning to Case 2, except that here $F_N$ is directed radially outwards and
$\displaystyle F_N = mg \cos \theta - \frac {mv^2} R
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow mg \cos \theta \ge \frac {mv^2} R$
In this case, as $\theta$ increases from $0$ to $\frac \pi 2$, then $\cos \theta$ decreases from $1$ down to $0$ while $v$ increases. So there will certainly come a point on the upper half of the track where
$\displaystyle mg \cos \theta = \frac {mv^2} R$
and after this point the marble will leave the surface of the track and will travel ballistically.

I also have trouble deriving a relationship among tangential acceleration, radial acceleration, tangential velocity, and experienced normal force

This approach is too complex. A much simpler approach is to derive $v$ as a function of $\theta$ using conservation of energy. In Case 1, for example, the height of the marble relative to the centre of the track is $h = R \cos (\pi - \theta)$. We know (since there is no friction) that the sum of the marble's KE and PE is constant, so
$\displaystyle \frac 1 2 mv^2 + mgR \cos (\pi - \theta)$
is constant. If we are given $v$ at some point on the track then we can $v$ for any other value of $\theta$.


The answer is in the image of case 1
Similar approach is also for case 2
